# Parse XML with Namespaces C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

After Posting to a certain URL, I get the following Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
   <soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode>123</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Lorem Ipsum</faultstring>
    <detail>
      <ns1:Service xmlns:ns1="http://www.bla.org/">
       <messageId>321</messageId>
       <text>Test Text</text>
       <variables>19</variables>
       <variables>20</variables>
      </ns1:Service>
    </detail>
   </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to Parse it and use the Values

I tried to Parse the XmlString to the following Class:

```
public class ClassXml
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Envelope
    {

        private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public EnvelopeBody Body
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bodyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bodyField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBody
    {

        private EnvelopeBodyFault faultField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public EnvelopeBodyFault Fault
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBodyFault
    {

        private string faultcodeField;

        private string faultstringField;

        private detail detailField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public string faultcode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultcodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultcodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public string faultstring
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultstringField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultstringField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public detail detail
        {
            get
            {
                return this.detailField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.detailField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class detail
    {

        private Service serviceField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.bla.org/")]
        public Service Service
        {
            get
            {
                return this.serviceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.serviceField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.bla.org/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.bla.org/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Service
    {

        private string messageIdField;

        private string textField;

        private ulong[] variablesField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public string messageId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.messageIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.messageIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public string text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.textField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.textField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("variables", Namespace = "")]
        public ulong[] variables
        {
            get
            {
                return this.variablesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.variablesField = value;
            }
        }
    }




}
```

But I got the error:

```
Exception Occured while trying to parse XML String
<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected.
```

Apparently I can't parse an XML with namespaces like I parse a normal XML

How can I parse this one and get the values?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I tried to deserialize your classes, and it worked fine.  See the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2rLCSi).  Can you create a reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: By the way, why are you nesting your actual classes inside an outer `ClassXml`?  It seems unnecessary.

Comment: @dbc notice when you deserialized my class, it returned the elements name as <body> and <fault>, while the provided XML has <soap:body> and <soap:fault>, therefore it doesnt recognize them as the same.

Comment: No, the classes were deserialized successfully, otherwise *nothing* would have been read.  When *re-serialized*, the `XmlSerializer` happens to chose a different namespace *prefix* that was chosen in the original XML, but that doesn't matter, the prefix is just a local lookup into the list of active namespace URIs.  See http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: @dbc what do I change in my code in order to be able to read it?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut As has been shown to you in the dotnetfiddle, your code works.  Without being able to reproduce your problem, it's not really possible to tell you why it doesn't work.  How are you deserializing your input?  Do you create the `XmlSerailizer` correctly (for the correct type)?